# laravel 5.1 middleware class not exist

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

I have implemented my own middleware on local machine. It is working fine on local machine. But, when I  uploaded the files on server, then it gives the error like middleware class not exist. Same error given when I created the custom helper.

Answer (score 1):

> then it gives the error like middleware class not exist.

If your server is a `Linux` system, you need to check if the case is correct.

Please provide more information, such as `middleware`, `help` content.

Sorry I can't just comment